# how to show ng-repeat horizontal?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-ng-repeat

this is an angularjs and bootstrap. I need to use ng-repeat horizontally. how can I use CSS or bootstrap to show my thumbnails horizontally ?

```
<div class="row">
    <ul class="col-md-4" id="phones">
        <li class="thumbnail" ng-repeat="phone in topSmartPhone">
            <img src="{{phone.img}}" alt="" />
            <div class="caption">
                <h3>{{phone.name}}</h3>
                <p><strong>Size : </strong> {{phone.size}}</p>
                <p><strong>RAM :</strong> {{phone.ram}}</p>
                <p><strong>Camera :</strong> {{phone.camera}}</p>
                <p><strong>Battry :</strong> {{phone.battery}}</p>
                <p id="description">{{phone.discription}}</p>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: `float`, or `display`

Comment: i used "display: inline-block" but not working !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ng-repeat must be in ul element not li.

```
<div class="row">
        <ul id="" class="col-md-4 col-xs-6" ng-repeat="phone in topSmartPhone">
            <li class="thumbnail">
                <img src="{{phone.img}}" alt="" />
                <div class="caption">
                    <h3>{{phone.name}}</h3>
                    <p><strong>Size : </strong> {{phone.size}}</p>
                    <p><strong>RAM :</strong> {{phone.ram}}</p>
                    <p><strong>Camera :</strong> {{phone.camera}}</p>
                    <p><strong>Battry :</strong> {{phone.battery}}</p>
                    <p id="description">{{phone.discription}}</p>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

So if I understand correctly you have multiple thumbnails?
In that case the CSS would look like this:

```
.thumbnail{ 
   display: inline-block;
   width: 19%; //this would be if you would perhaps want 5 thumbnails in a row I have know idea how many you want on a row
}
```

Comment: No problem at all if you select my comment as the answer, this will help other people with the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

try this.

```js
var app= angular.module("myapp",[]);
        app.controller("ctrl",function($scope){
            $scope.items = [1,2,3,4,5];

        });
```

```css
.thumbnail{
   float:left;
    width: 60px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="ctrl">
   <div class="row">
    <ul class="col-md-4" id="phones">
        <li class="thumbnail" ng-repeat="item in items">
           
            <div class="caption">
                <h3>{{item}}</h3>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

remove **class="col-md-4"** from **ul** element and add **class="thumbnail col-md-12"**  to **li** element